# Depends: libgcc-s1 (>=3.0) but it is not installable (Bitcoind wallet dependency problem on Debian)

Tags: bitcoind, wallet, linux, installation, dependencies

On Debian I successfully compiled `.bitcoind` without a wallet, but now I need the wallet.

`./configure` tells me I need Berkeley CXX headers. Searching for how to do this on Debian brings up a bunch of Ubuntu answers saying to do either

```
sudo apt-get install libdb4.8-dev libdb4.8++ libdb4.8++-dev
```

after having added a PPA, or

```
wget http://download.oracle.com/berkeley-db/db-4.8.30.zip
unzip db-4.8.30.zip
cd db-4.8.30
cd build_unix/
../dist/configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-cxx
make
make install
```

Both solutions throw errors. I'm focusing on the 1st solution.

The first solution throws this error:

> ```
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>  libdb4.8++ : Depends: libgcc-s1 (>= 3.0) but it is not installable
> ```

I'm not sure, but I assume this may be an Ubuntu vs. Debian issue? How can I bypass it?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need a newer version of gcc.

This helped me fix for Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140183/install-gcc-9-on-ubuntu-18-04

TL&DR: adds custom PPA repo so you will able to upgrade:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt update
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```